# How to sort an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist

I have a class named Fruit. I am creating a list of this class and adding each fruit in the list. I want to sort this list based on the order of fruit name.

```
public class Fruit{

    private String fruitName;
    private String fruitDesc;
    private int quantity;

    public String getFruitName() {
        return fruitName;
    }
    public void setFruitName(String fruitName) {
        this.fruitName = fruitName;
    }
    public String getFruitDesc() {
        return fruitDesc;
    }
    public void setFruitDesc(String fruitDesc) {
        this.fruitDesc = fruitDesc;
    }
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

and I am creating its list using for loop

```
List<Fruit>  fruits= new ArrayList<Fruit>();

Fruit fruit;
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
   fruit = new fruit();
   fruit.setname(...);
   fruits.add(fruit);
}
```

and I need to sort this arrayList using the fruit name of each object in the list

how??

Comment: Try this : https://dzone.com/articles/sorting-java-arraylist

Answer (score 427, accepted):

Use a `Comparator` like this:

```
List<Fruit> fruits= new ArrayList<Fruit>();

Fruit fruit;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
  fruit = new Fruit();
  fruit.setname(...);
  fruits.add(fruit);
}

// Sorting
Collections.sort(fruits, new Comparator<Fruit>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Fruit fruit2, Fruit fruit1)
        {

            return  fruit1.fruitName.compareTo(fruit2.fruitName);
        }
    });
```

Now your fruits list is sorted based on `fruitName`.

Comment: Either this approach, using a `Comparator`, or @BMT's approach of making the objects implement `Comparable` would work. The difference is that by implementing `Comparable`, you're saying that the ordering is a fundamental part of the nature of the objects (like integers or strings), whereas by using a `Comparator`, you're saying that in this specific context, you want them ordered in a certain way.

Comment: what about the order of the sorting ?? ascending or descending ??

Comment: if the fruits names are case sensitive then you should use compareToIgnoreCase

Comment: I think the answer given under the section "since java-8" here is more succinct: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2784576/1372202

Comment: @Silent_Rebel It's ascending. You need to reverse the list after sorting it if you want it descending. It's tedious, agreed.

Comment: For those coming from Google, see here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html The documentation says, "Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second." Note that you can also use e.g. Integer.compare(int a, int b);

Comment: Late in the game....But does not acsending or Descending depend on the positioning of the objcts in the compare function? Compare fruit1 with fruit2, would give a different result than comparing fruit2 with fruit1??

Answer (score 92):

Implement **Comparable** interface to Fruit.

```
public class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit> {
```

It implements the method

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(Fruit fruit) {
        //write code here for compare name
    }
```

Then do call sort method

```
Collections.sort(fruitList);
```

Comment: `Collections.sort(..)` also works for `ArrayList<T>` where `T` is `Integer`, `Long`, `String`, which all have their `compareTo(..)` methods implemented.

Comment: Comparable should be Comparable<Fruit> to work with compareTo(Fruit fruit)

Comment: How would your approach look like if I wanted to add multiple different sort options, for example Override the compareTo method to order by the object name, but add another one for sorting by age, product id etc. etc.

Comment: @b101: In that case you would write multiple Comparators and just insert the right one at the right place. Something like:
``Comparator comp1 = new Comparator<Fruit>() {
        @\Override
        public int compare(Fruit fruit2, Fruit fruit1) {
            return  fruit1.fruitName.compareTo(fruit2.fruitName);
        }
    });
Collection.sort(fruitList, comp1);``

Answer (score 14):

Try [BeanComparator](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Apache-Common/BeanComparatorSortingbasedonPropertiesofclass.htm) from Apache [Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanComparator.html).

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanComparator;


BeanComparator fieldComparator = new BeanComparator("fruitName");
Collections.sort(fruits, fieldComparator);
```