# Sorting ArrayList alphabetically

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an ArrayList "contactList" in the class "ContactGroup" that contains an object of another class "Contact". The object contains a String for "name" and an int for "phoneNum".

How do I sort the ArrayList in alphabetically order? Any help would be much appreciated

I tried unsuccessfully using:

```
 Collections.sort(contactList);
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441846/how-sort-a-arraylist-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement the `Comparable` interface. Look it up on the web, your code should result in something like this:

```
public class Contact implements Comparable<Contact> {

...

    public int compareTo(Contact c) {
        return c.getString().compareTo(this.string)
    }
}
```

Assuming the string is stored in a variable `String string`.

Now try to sort!

Answer (score 1):

Your Contact type should implement Comparable:

```
public class Contact implements Comparable<Contact>
{
 @Override
    public int compareTo(Contact o) {
        return o.name.compareTo(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Contact> l = new ArrayList<Contact>();
l.sort(new Comparator<Contact>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Contact o1, Contact o2){        
        return o1.getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(o2.getName().toLowerCase());
    }           
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This way is fairly simple:

```
Collections.sort(list, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

**Edit** I hit the post button to fast. You need to make your `Contact` class comparable for `Collections.sort(list)` to work so it knows which field to use for sorting (you can use comparable for more advanced sorting, but here all you need is to use the `name` to sort). To do this just add `implements Comparable<Contact>` to your `Contact` class and implement the one method in this interface `compareTo(Contact o)` like so:

```
public class Contact implements Comparable<Contact> {

    public int compareTo(Contact o) {
         return name.compareToIgnoreCase(o.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Comparator:

```
class ContactComparator implements Comparator<Contact> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Contact c1, Contact c2) {
        return c1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(c2.getName());
    }
}

//getName being getter for a attribute name(say)
Collections.sort(contactList, new ContactComparator());
```

In above code snippet, you could also use compare(..) flavor depending upon your requirement.

Then you can sort using Collections.sort(contactList, new ContactComparator());

or you could also make your Contact class implement Comparable, where you could do similar thing as above inside compareTo(..)

and use Collections.sort(contactList);