# Sorting of a Class ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an ArrayList that is a list of a class I made called "Profile". This profile contains an integer called "tokens". How can I generate an instance of this arraylist but with it organizing them by which profile has the most Tokens?

Here is my Profile class

```
public class Profile 
{
    private String name;
    private int tokens;

    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public int getTokens() { return this.tokens; }
}
```

And I have all the profiles stored in an ArrayList such as this...

```
public static List<Profile> PROFILES = new ArrayList<Profile>();
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441846/how-sort-a-arraylist-in-java

Comment: The convention for using capital letters for the name of an instance field extends to field values that are expected to be constant.  The requirements for this are that the field be 3 things: `static`, `final`, and immutable.  Your List field is both mutable and nonfinal, so you should not name it with capitals.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `Profile` has to implement the `Comparable` interface and override its `compareTo` method, in which you can compare the tokens' value, like this:

```
public class Profile implements Comparable<Profile>
{
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Profile p) {
        return p.tokens < this.tokens;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

```
    public class Profile implements Comparable<Profile>
    {
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Profile p) {
             if (p.tokens > this.tokens) { 
                 return -1; 
             } else if (p.tokens < this.tokens) { 
                 return 1; 
             } else 
                 return 0;
        }
    }
```

After that you are able to call `Collections.sort(PROFILES);`

Note that it is not recommended to write your variables with full capital letters. It would be better just simply `Profiles`

Comment: Eclipse is wanting to turn this method into a "public boolean" instead of "public int".

Comment: Then try 'return p.tokens.compareTo(this.tokens);'

Comment: Or better:
if (p.tokens > this.tokens) {
    return -1;
} else if (p.tokens < this.tokens) {
    return 1;
} else return 0;

Answer (score -1):

```
class Dog implements Comparator<Dog>, Comparable<Dog>{
   private String name;
   private int age;
   Dog(){
   }
   Dog(String n, int a){
      name = n;
      age = a;
   }
   public String getDogName(){
      return name;
   }
   public int getDogAge(){
      return age;
   }
   // Overriding the compareTo method
   public int compareTo(Dog d){
      return (this.name).compareTo(d.name);
   }
   // Overriding the compare method to sort the age 
   public int compare(Dog d, Dog d1){
      return d.age - d1.age;
   }
}

public class Example{

   public static void main(String args[]){
      // Takes a list o Dog objects
      List<Dog> list = new ArrayList<Dog>();

      list.add(new Dog("Shaggy",3));
      list.add(new Dog("Lacy",2));
      list.add(new Dog("Roger",10));
      list.add(new Dog("Tommy",4));
      list.add(new Dog("Tammy",1));
      Collections.sort(list);// Sorts the array list

      for(Dog a: list)//printing the sorted list of names
         System.out.print(a.getDogName() + ", ");

      // Sorts the array list using comparator
      Collections.sort(list, new Dog());
      System.out.println(" ");
      for(Dog a: list)//printing the sorted list of ages
         System.out.print(a.getDogName() +"  : "+
         a.getDogAge() + ", ");
   }
}

This would produce the following result:
Lacy, Roger, Shaggy, Tammy, Tommy,
Tammy  : 1, Lacy  : 2, Shaggy  : 3, Tommy  : 4, Roger  : 10,
```