# Render from highest to lowest game objects with z cord

Tags: libgdx

so I'am currently working with the game (using libgdx) and I want to make that objects(textures) from arraylist WorldObjects which has lowest float z; to draw(render).So I need to make that game would render from lowest to highest float z;

example:
8, 8, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1.4

```
ArrayList<WorldObject> worldObjects = new ArrayList<WorldObject>();
```

then this is world object class

```
public class WorldObject {
Texture texture;
float x, y, z;
public WorldObject(Texture texture, float x, float y, float z) {
    this.texture = texture;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
}}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? Any code? Do you use Stage and Actors? Watching at the marble tells me you should Sort your textures in the renderlist and give them a Z index.

Comment: I haveArrayList<WorldObject> worldObjects = new ArrayList<WorldObject>(); which contains worldobject's and then i cant figure out what to do so that worldobject with lowest float Z; would draw first

Comment: show us the renderingcode and the world objects else we can just guess. Moreover sorting a ArrayList is preaty simple and already asked several times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort an ArrayList in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441846/how-to-sort-an-arraylist-in-java) Simply change the comperator to a z order comperator.

Comment: how can I sort an arraylist ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441846/how-to-sort-an-arraylist-in-java as already tagt.