# Java: sort a list of lists with sortOrder

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

I'm working on sorting of list of lists and below is my current code snippet

I have employee POJO as like below

```
List<Employee> employeesList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
employeesList.add(employee01);
employeesList.add(employee02);
```

Now i have employee POJO contains

```
private int employeeId;
private String employeeName;
private List<EmployeeProgram> employeePrgoram = new ArrayList<EmployeeProgram>();
private int sortOrder;
```

Now, EmployeeProgram object contains

```
private int programId;
private String programName;
private int programCount;
private int sortOrder;
```

Now, i want to assign sortOrder for "Employee" as well as "EmployeeProgram"

I know collections.sort with Comparator works. but not sure how it can be ?

Help me in this context. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

Comment: This is unclear of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18441978/3042145) is a sample how sorting of array lists can be done. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Comparable interface then override compareTo method as follow

```
public int compareTo(Employee emp){  
  if(sortOrder==emp.sortOrder)  
    return 0;  
  else if(sortOrder>emp.sortOrder)  
    return 1;  
  else  
    return -1;  
}
```

repeat same for EmployeeProgram class
and override this method

```
public int compareTo(EmployeeProgram empProg){  
  if(sortOrder==empProg.sortOrder)  
    return 0;  
  else if(sortOrder>empProg.sortOrder)  
    return 1;  
  else  
    return -1;  
}
```

and use

Collection.sort(employeesList);

Comment: i have to set the Employee "sortorder" & EmployeeProgram "sortorder"with respective to maximum "programCount" in  EmployeeProgram.