# Sort Java ArrayList according to object property

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, compare, comparator

How can I sort an ArrayList of type: `List<Map<String, Object>>` according to a property of that list, when I have the properties in the right order as a String?

e.g. I have a big list containing of ids and names. And I have the ids in the wanted order in a string. How can I order the list according to the string?

Comment: Searching for "java sort list" gives lots of Q&A. Downvoting for failing to do any basic searching.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer the following StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441846/how-to-sort-an-arraylist-in-java).

In summary, you could create a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for the corresponding class; or implement the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.

Comment: The word duplicate in there indicates that well, duplicates are around. Putting up an answer that **only** links to another answer, sorry, that is, well, lame?!

Comment: @GhostCat i'm a newbie in answering stackoverflow questions.... i'll take the criticism constructively... thanks

Comment: I like your attitude. I reworded the answer a bit, and upvoted; just to appreciate that!

Comment: @GhostCat :) thanks