# How to sort String[] in List by timestamp?

Tags: java, sorting, comparable

```
List<String[]> data = Importer.readCsv("test.csv");
```

A `String[]` item looks like this:

1. Position: name (String)
2. Position: `2017-03-14 18:22:44.149` (String)

What is a good approach in order to sort the list by the timestamp descending? I search for a solution without creating new Objects.

Comment: Couldn't you make  a list of objects? it's a better approach

Comment: I could, but later I have to use functions which are using the Array. So later a have to transform the object back

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort an ArrayList in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441846/how-to-sort-an-arraylist-in-java)

Comment: You just have to implement your `Comparator` to what you want

Comment: without creating new object?

Comment: `Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<String[]>() {
   @Override
   public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {

    return o1[1].compareTo(o2[1]);
   }

  });` this should work as needed

Comment: Have you read about customer comparators, i.e. `Comparator<String[]>` ?

Comment: To sort it, you have to treat the string array as an object so you will have to trasnform it 2 times, it doesn't make a big difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Collection.sort() and Comparator.comparing(), I find those easy to read when coming back to it later:

```
data.sort(Comparator.comparing((String[] o) -> o[1]).reversed());
```

You can compare the timestamp without conversion, as the format is "correctly" ordering the fields.

---

If you are confined to Java 7, there will be more boilerplate:

```
Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<String[]>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2)
    {
        return o2[1].compareTo(o1[1]);
        // return -o1[1].compareTo(o2[1]);
    }
});
```

Note that I need to compare `o2` to `o1` in this order or negate the result of comparing `o1` to `o2` to order the data descending. This becomes much more obvious in the first approach.

Comment: I guess it's a Java 8 solution?

Comment: Yes, all those methods were introduced in Java 8. I'll add a Java 7 solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom `Comparator` that takes the second element in each array and converts it to a `Timestamp`. Note that a Comparator's function can't throw an exception, so you'd have to catch the potential `ParseException` and deal with it:

```
Function<String[], Date> parser = s -> {
    try {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS").parse(s[1]);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return null;
    }
};

list.sort(Comparator.comparing(parser));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, thank you very much for your suggestions and impulses.
Special Thanks goes to [XtremeBaumer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7109162/xtremebaumer)!
Following code does the job too:

```
List<String[]> data = importer.readCsv(context, csvFile);


Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<String[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String[] item1, String[] item2) {

        String dateString1 = item1[1];
        String dateString2 = item2[1];

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

        Date date1 = null;
        Date date2 = null;

        try {
            date1 = format.parse(dateString1);
            date2 = format.parse(dateString2);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }

        // dateString1 is an earlier date than dateString2
        return date1.compareTo(date2);
    }
});
```