# How to sort inner list which is a value of a map in Java?

Tags: java

It's more of a Java question (although I'm using Firebase). I'm trying to understand what's best way to sort a list. I'm trying to create the following map:

```
Map<Character,List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>> docs;
```

In order to build this map, I iterate over the documents in my collection, get the first letter of each one and insert the document into the list where the key is the letter. 
The code:

```
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot current_document : value) {
    char letter = getFirstLetter(current_document.getString("type"));
    List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> list = docs.get(letter);
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(current_document);
        docs.put(letter, list);
    } else {
        list.add(current_document);
    }
}
```

In order to make the `docs` map sorted, I use `TreeMap`:

```
docs = new TreeMap<>();
```

But how can I make the list of documents be sorted by the field `type` (String)?

**EDIT** Sorry for not mentioning it, `value` is of type `QuerySnapshot` (firebase). Also I'm using Android's Java API 16 (which means I don't have java 8).

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Basically I'm using Android's Java so I believe it something between 6 and 7.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441846/how-to-sort-an-arraylist-in-java
You just iterate through the map, get the List for each index, and sort it. If you need it to persist use LinkedList

Comment: Could you use `TreeSet` instead of `ArrayList `?

Comment: @MateuszKorwel Yes

Comment: @abuka123  So your lists do not contain duplicates or you don't care if some of them are removed?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `TreeSet` instead of `ArrayList`, it can look like this. More you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8725470/4228138

```
Map<Character,Set<QueryDocumentSnapshot>> docs;

...

Comparator<QueryDocumentSnapshot> comparator = new Comparator<QueryDocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(QueryDocumentSnapshot o1, QueryDocumentSnapshot o2) {
        return o1.getString("type").compareTo(o2.getString("type"));
    }
};

for (QueryDocumentSnapshot currentDocument : value) {
    char letter = getFirstLetter(currentDocument.getString("type"));
    Set<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documents = docs.get(letter);
    if (documents == null) {
        documents = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
        documents.add(currentDocument);
        docs.put(letter, documents);
    } else {
        documents.add(currentDocument);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Comparator` and apply it to each List in the map.  Since you are not changing the actual List reference you can sort in place.  Note that I presumed that "type" returned a String.  This may need to be changed.

Also, TreeMap has nothing to do with sorting the values.  That would only sort the keys to the map.

```
Comparator<QueryDocumentSnapshot> comp = new CompareByType();
for (List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> list : docs.values()) {
        Collections.sort(list,comp);
}
```

Here is the `Comparator` class

```
class CompareByType implements Comparator<QueryDocumentSnapshot> {
     public int compare(QueryDocumentSnapshot a, QueryDocumentSnapshot b) {
         String a = QueryDocumentSnapshot.getString("type");
         String b = QueryDocumentSnapshot.getString("type");
         return a.compareTo(b);
     }
}
```

And here is a slight mod to your map creation.  You don't need the else clause because list will always have a valid list when it is time to add the document.

```
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot current_document : value) {
    char letter = getFirstLetter(current_document.getString("type"));
    List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> list = docs.get(letter);
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        docs.put(letter, list);
    }
    // At this point you will always have a list to access.
    // you can add the current document here
    list.add(current_document);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to sort all `QueryDocumentSnapshot`s before they are classified by first key. If the collection is sorted before, then each particular list will be sorted as well.

Hence, add

```
Collections.sort(value, Comparator.comparing(q -> q.getString("type")));
```

before the code you posted (I assume `value` a `List`, for general collection change it to stream sorting).

Answer (score -1):

You can

1. Let the `QueryDocumentSnapshot` implement `Compareableable<QueryDocumentSnapshot>`. So it will use your implementation to sort the entries.
2. Provide a `Comparator` to the TreeMap constructor: `TreeMap(Comparator<? super K> comparator)`
   The comparator can look like this:

```java
(o1, o2) -> o1.getString("type").compareTo(o2.getString("type"))
```

Comment: `QueryDocumentSnapshot` is not mine, it's from firebase.